# Bootstrap popup window 3 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make a popup window with bootstrap. I modified some codes from a template. It should have 3 columns. 1st column picture, 2nd column text and 3rd column is price and button+icon. This is going to be a list with several  similar rows. Here I just put one row to make simple. The footer is going to be some text. The problem is I can't get the 3rd column to the right position. I tried with clearfix, etc. Any suggestions?

Please note that, these codes have several unsolved issue. Please ignore those things. That's not the first priority. Tks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Wish List</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 ">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="The car i dream about" data-caption="something" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="A alt text">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 clearfix">
                
                    <p ><a href="#">Product Title</a></p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>Description.dfdasfjsadfdasldfdslafjlsadfsldfjsdljf</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 clearfix" >
                    <p>price$6.99</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Buy now</button>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span> view of 1-5 of </span>
                <select>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="5">10</option>
                      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a 'row' , and forgot  a 'class=' , and you can remove the clearfix

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Wish List</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 ">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="The car i dream about" data-caption="something" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="A alt text">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 clearfix">
                
                    <p ><a href="#">Product Title</a></p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>Description.dfdasf jsadfdasld fdslafjlsadf sldfjsdljf</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 clearfix" >
                    <p>price$6.99</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Buy now</button>
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
         </div>     
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span> view of 1-5 of </span>
                <select>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="5">10</option>
                      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tks Ixer, nice I can see the result from snippet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly it's number 1 below, but here are a couple other things to consider:

1. **You left out the keyword `class` in the markup for the second column.** This is pretty important.
2. You don't really need the `clearfix` class. If you wrap the whole thing in a `row` div then it will do the line breaking for you pretty well.
3. The columns should always add up to 12 - when you have three `col-lg-3`s you'll end up with something that is left-aligned and only takes up 3/4ths of the modal.
4. The columns for the smaller screen sizes will get bumped up to the next ones, so `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3` is the same as saying `col-xs-4 col-lg-3`. The less CSS rules that need to be applied for the same result the better.
5. In your example you have a really long word in the description, which causes it to overflow into the next column. You might want to account for that situation by playing around with things like `word-wrap` and `text-overflow`.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Modals</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Wish List</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <a class="thumbnail" href="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-image-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-title="The car i dream about" data-caption="something" data-image="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" data-target="#image-gallery">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/car-image.jpg" alt="A alt text">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <p><a href="#">Product Title</a>
              </p>
              <p class="text-warning"><small>Description.dfdasfjsadfdasldfdslafjlsadfsldfjsdljf</small>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <p>price$6.99</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Buy now</button>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <span> view of 1-5 of </span>
          <select>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="5">10</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```